# Read cell's value selected from drop-down-list

Tags: java, excel, drop-down-menu, apache-poi

In my Excel file, I have a drop-down-list applying to some cells and I want to get the specific value that is selected for a cell. I always get empty string when I try to get this value.

I do search for this but all the answers only give instructions about how to get all the possible values in the drop-down-list. I also think about removing this drop-down-list but I want to keep it if it's possible.

My Java source code for this using apache-POI:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("abc.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
for (Row row: sheet) {
    String value = formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(3));
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Image of drop-down list.

Due to company policies, i can only upload this small size image. Sorry for inconvenience.

[Drop-down-list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTJHm.png)

[DataValidation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXMv0.jpg)

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Sorry about that. I want to read value of excel's cells using java code. Currently, i use apache-poi library to read excel file but i have trouble with reading value selected from a drop-down-list. This question is to ask if there is someone know how to deal with it.

Comment: At first you should determine what kind of drop-down that is. Is it a data validation list constraint in the cell? But if so the selected value would be in the cell and your code would get it. Or is it a form control? Or is it an ActiveX control? Please determine what it is and do showing a screen shot of the sheet which contains the drop-downs.

Comment: @AxelRichter Image has been attached. Please kindly take a look at it and tell me your opinion. I think my drop-down list is data-validation type.

Comment: If it is data validation list in the cell, then the selected value would be in the cell and your code would get it. But what cell is it? From your code `row.getCell(3)` it would must be in column 3, which is column `D`. What value does `DataFormatter` get from that cell? Or is the data validation in column `C`? That would be `row.getCell(2)` since column index starts with 0 = `A`.

Comment: @AxelRichter I realize these cells are in column G. Column C, D, E, F have been merged to 1 column and i think index of column G is 3. I try it again with 6 and it works now. That is so stupid. Aw. Anyway, many thanks for your helps.